# Stack characters from column into one cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I received a sheet that is not formatted well and I was wondering if there is any easier way of going through 2,000 rows of data than going one by one.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7N3j.jpg)

Comment: Can you please clarify what is the desired format? I'd suggest you to provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, clearly indicating the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

With the following assumptions:

1. First name column is always populated.
2. Address column is not more than 3 rows.
3. The Name is the distinction that starts a new Name/Address combination.

Then the following formulas will work with little modification needed.

**Return the name** (Cell H1 formula):

```
 =IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",CONCAT(A1, " ", B1))
```

Drag it down entirely. If you run into the scenario where column B (not column A) has the name, then slightly modify that formula above.

**Return the address in one cell** (Cell I1 formula):

```
=IF(LEN(H1)>0,CONCATENATE(IF(ISBLANK(D1),"",D1),IF(ISBLANK(D2),"", CHAR(10) & D2),IF(ISBLANK(D3),"", CHAR(10) & D3)),"")
```

This will ignore blanks and return the cells with data. Just change the **column format to Wrap Text** and copy the formula down entirely.

[image]

If your address spans more than 3 rows, then just tweak the formula with the same format to get that additional row.

Comment: I just realized you asked about google sheets (excel tag was removed). I'm not a sheets user, so hopefully these formulas work the same as they do in Excel.